# syscall: 'spawn xdg-open' inside docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, vite

I am build my page inside the docker, and then after I build finish it, it should be push to docker hub. and then I want to deploy it like:

```
docker run -d --name commerce_dash  -p4505:8000 -e NODE_ENV=production r2day/commerce-dash
```

everything works fine, for now. but When I check the logs, and it shows me:

```
  VITE v3.2.2  ready in 641 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:8000/
  ➜  Network: http://172.17.0.19:8000/
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn xdg-open',
  path: 'xdg-open',
  spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:8000/' ]
}

Node.js v19.0.0
```

My docker file like:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock vite.config.ts ./

# COPY .env.production ./.env.production

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENV BASE_PATH admin

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build  && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV BASE_PATH admin

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/vite.config.ts ./vite.config.ts
COPY --from=builder /app/packages ./packages


USER nextjs

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PORT 8000
ENV BASE_PATH admin

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/vite", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Anyway, I can run it on my MacBook by using

```
node_modules/.bin/vite
```

Comment: Vite has an [option](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-open) to try to open the built page in your browser, but this won't work in an isolated Docker container.  Has your Vite configuration enabled this option, or is there a command-line switch to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a React Vite app and I fixed it as [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) said.

In my vite.config.ts, I changed the open option to false and it worked!

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        watch: {
            usePolling: true
        },
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        strictPort: true,
        open: false, // previously set to true
        port: 3000
    }
});
```