# I'm trying to setup a Redux application using Docker but Vite is giving me Error: spawn xdg-open

Tags: reactjs, docker, redux, vite

I am working on containerizing a barebones redux application using Docker but when I docker compose up npm start works but it gives me an error related to xdg-open. I'm confused because I have my ports setup in the Dockerfile according to the redux application ports but still running into this issue.

This is my docker file:

```
    FROM node:alpine AS development  
    WORKDIR /react-frontend  
    COPY package.json .  
    COPY package-lock.json .  
    RUN npm i  
    COPY . .  
    CMD [ "npm", "start" ]  
    
    vite.config.js:  
    
    export default defineConfig({  
      plugins: [react()],  
      server: {  
        open: true,          //true  
      },  
      build: {  
        outDir: "build",  
        sourcemap: true,  
      },  
      test: {  
        globals: true,  
        environment: "jsdom",  
        setupFiles: "src/setupTests",  
        mockReset: true,  
      },  
    })
```

This is the error:

```
    VITE v4.5.0  ready in 980 ms  
    ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/  
    ➜  Network: use --host to expose  
    node:events:493  
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
    ^  
    
    Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT  
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)  
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)  
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)  
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:  
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)  
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)  
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {  
    errno: -2,  
    code: 'ENOENT',  
    syscall: 'spawn xdg-open',  
    path: 'xdg-open',  
    spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:5173/' ]  
    }  
    
    Node.js v21.1.0
```

I tried switching open: true in vite.config to open: false but that just led to the suppression of the error, however the localhost:5173 page just had "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Comment: [syscall: 'spawn xdg-open' inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273133/syscall-spawn-xdg-open-inside-docker) suggests setting `server: { open: false }`; does that resolve this issue?  You will also need [running a vite dev server inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container) `host: true` for the container to be accessible.